# Asp Identity: how implement on mysql

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

In my ASP.NET MVC 5 project I want implement the ASP.NET Identity 2.0 with MySQL database instead of SQL Server.

I have read the following tutorial:

[Implementing a Custom MySQL ASP.NET Identity Storage Provider](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/implementing-a-custom-mysql-aspnet-identity-storage-provider)

So I have created the database first with the script found in that tutorial but when I register a new user I have an error:

> it's not found the table "aspnetusers"

The script has created the table "users".

Which is the correct way to implement the Identity on MySQL? Which are the names of the tables?

Comment: Why don't you try changing the name of the table to aspnetusers?

Comment: yean and it works!! But i want know what is the default and correct way to implement identity on mysql

Comment: Good :).  One other way is to create a new MVC project in the latest version of VS and I believe that this has Identity Framework configured by default ready for code first database deployment.  You would of course need to change your storage mechanism from SQL to MySQL.  The actual naming of the tables has no bearing on whether Identity Framework is correctly set up or not... I set up Identity Framework code first with an existing user database and I kept it named to my liking